# Azure DevOps Build Validation use latest run

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

i want to prevent the User from merging a PR if a specific pipeline failed. But i don't want to trigger the pipeline again but i want to use the latest run because the pipeline is a scheduled systemtest.

The "Build Validation" policy has no option to check the latest run of a pipeline.
[Add build policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzOSH.png)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such method can use Build Validation to check the latest run instead of  triggering new pipeline.

Refer to this doc: [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

> A build validation policy queues a new build when a new PR is created or changes are pushed to an existing PR that targets the branch.

Triggering new build is the default behavior of the Build validation in Branch Policy.

I suggest you can add an extra pipeline to set the branch policy, in the extra pipeline you can use the Rest API: [Latest - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to check the latest running status of the target pipeline

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it as you described.

Comment: I've another problem now. I saw that it is not possible to define a Build Validation with a build which uses another Repo. Then the build cannot be queued (nothing happens after the user clicks on 'Queue')

Do you know any solution for this? Is it even possible?